# OpenGL: VBO Textures not working when loaded from a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, opengl, textures, vbo

I'm really new to this community. I'm sorry for any mistakes in advance.I'm making a game like minecraft with GLFW and OpenGL. The problem is, it just renders three faces correctly and the other faces have a wierd glitch. Here is my code:

main.py

```
# imports
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

# internal imports
from core.renderer import *
from player import *

if not glfw.init():
    raise Exception("glfw can not be initialized!")

window = glfw.create_window(800, 500, "PyCraft", None, None)
glfw.make_context_current(window)
renderer = TerrainRenderer(window)
player = Player(window)

renderer.texture_manager.add_from_folder("assets/textures/block/")
renderer.texture_manager.save("atlas.png")
renderer.texture_manager.bind()

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
glCullFace(GL_BACK)
glEnable(GL_FOG)
glFogfv(GL_FOG_COLOR, (GLfloat * int(8))(0.5, 0.69, 1.0, 10))
glHint(GL_FOG_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE)
glFogi(GL_FOG_MODE, GL_LINEAR)
glFogf(GL_FOG_START, 30)
glFogf(GL_FOG_END, 100)

# get window size
def get_window_size():
    width, height = glfw.get_window_size(window)
    return width, height

def _setup_3d():
    w, h = get_window_size()

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(70, w / h, 0.1, 1000)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

def _update_3d():
    _setup_3d()
    glViewport(0, 0, *get_window_size())

def add_cube(x, y, z):
    X, Y, Z = x + 1, y + 1, z + 1
    renderer.add((x, Y, Z,  X, Y, Z,  X, Y, z,  x, Y, z), renderer.texture_manager.get_texture("grass"))
    renderer.add((x, y, z, X, y, z, X, y, Z, x, y, Z), renderer.texture_manager.get_texture("grass"))
    renderer.add((x, y, z,  x, y, Z,  x, Y, Z,  x, Y, z), renderer.texture_manager.get_texture("grass"))
    renderer.add((X, y, Z,  X, y, z,  X, Y, z,  X, Y, Z), renderer.texture_manager.get_texture("grass"))
    renderer.add((x, y, Z,  X, y, Z,  X, Y, Z,  x, Y, Z), renderer.texture_manager.get_texture("grass"))
    renderer.add((X, y, z,  x, y, z,  x, Y, z,  X, Y, z), renderer.texture_manager.get_texture("grass"))

add_cube(0, 0, -2)

# mainloop
while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    _update_3d()
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.7, 1, 1.0)

    player.update()
    renderer.render()

    glfw.poll_events()
    glfw.swap_buffers(window)

glfw.terminate()
```

renderer.py:

```
# imports
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
from ctypes import *
from core.texture_manager import *
import threading
import numpy as np
from core.logger import *

glfw.init()

class TerrainRenderer:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.to_add = []
        self._len = 0

        self.parent = window

        self.vertices = []
        self.texCoords = []

        self.create_vbo(window)

        self.texture_manager = TextureAtlas()

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
        glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)


    def shared_context(self, window):
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, glfw.FALSE)
        window2 = glfw.create_window(500,500, "Window 2", None, window)
        glfw.make_context_current(window2)
        self.event.set()

        while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
            if len(self.to_add) > 0:
                i = self.to_add.pop(0)

                vertices = np.array(i[0], dtype=np.float32)
                texture_coords = np.array(i[1], dtype=np.float32)

                bytes_vertices = vertices.nbytes
                bytes_texCoords = texture_coords.nbytes

                verts = (GLfloat * len(vertices))(*vertices)
                texCoords = (GLfloat * len(texture_coords))(*texture_coords)

                log_vertex_addition((vertices, texture_coords), (bytes_vertices, bytes_texCoords), self._len*4, len(self.to_add))

                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
                glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self._len, bytes_vertices, verts)
                glVertexPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
                glFlush()
                
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_1)
                glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self._len, bytes_texCoords, texCoords)
                glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
                glFlush()

                glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
                glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)

                self.vertices += i[0]
                self.texCoords += i[1]
                
                self._len += bytes_vertices

            glfw.poll_events()
            glfw.swap_buffers(window2)
        glfw.terminate()

    def create_vbo(self, window):
        self.vbo, self.vbo_1 = glGenBuffers (2)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 64000000, None, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_1)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 64000000, None, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        glfw.make_context_current(None)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.shared_context, args=[window], daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        self.event.wait()
        glfw.make_context_current(window)

    def add(self, vertices, texCoords):
        self.to_add.append((tuple(vertices), tuple(texCoords)))

    def render(self):
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)

        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        glVertexPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_1)
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)

        glDrawArrays (GL_QUADS, 0, self._len)

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glDisable(GL_BLEND)
```

Output

[image: Output]

It is expected that all faces of the above cube are lime.

Right now, it shows no errors, but it does not render the cube properly. The attached GIF explains what I mean.

When I use this code in renderer.py, it works just fine!

```
# imports
import glfw, numpy
from OpenGL.GL import *
from ctypes import *
from core.texture_manager import *

glfw.init()

class VBOManager:
    def __init__(self, renderer):
        self.renderer = renderer
        self.run()
    
    def run(self):
        for i in self.renderer.to_add[:self.renderer.to_add_count]:
            self.renderer.vertices.extend(i[0])
            self.renderer.texCoords.extend(i[1])

            self.renderer.to_add.remove(i)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.renderer.vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(self.renderer.vertices) * 4, (c_float * len(self.renderer.vertices))(*self.renderer.vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glFlush()
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
        glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.renderer.vbo_1)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(self.renderer.texCoords) * 4, (c_float * len(self.renderer.texCoords))(*self.renderer.texCoords), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glFlush()

class TerrainRenderer:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window

        self.vertices = []
        self.texCoords = []

        self.to_add = []
        self.to_add_count = 256

        self.vbo, self.vbo_1 = glGenBuffers (2)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12 * 4, None, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        self.vbo_manager = VBOManager(self)

        self.texture_manager = TextureAtlas()

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
        glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

    def render(self):
        try:
            self.vbo_manager.run()
        except RuntimeError:
            pass

        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        glVertexPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_1)
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)

        glDrawArrays (GL_QUADS, 0, len(self.vertices))
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glDisable(GL_BLEND)

    def add(self, posList, texCoords):
        self.to_add.append((numpy.array(posList), numpy.array(texCoords)))

    def update_vbo(self):
        pass
```

Why does this code work and not the previous one? Have I missed something?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I believe there is a problem with the texture. Have you tried rendering the texture to a quad first (before showing it to the cube)?

Comment: Have you analyzed your application through a graphics debugger? This is most likely just a logic error that is better solved interactively rather than someone reading through all this code and trying to debug it by inspection.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget Yes I have.

Comment: @the_Demongod Please tell me how I can do that, I have no idea what a graphics debugger is.

Comment: @somePythonProgrammer What is the output then?

Comment: @somePythonProgrammer it's just what it sounds like, it will allow you to inspect the internal state of the API during drawing. You can either use the proprietary one made by your GPU's vendor, or RenderDoc, which is platform agnostic.

Comment: I've fixed the issue, code for renderer.py: https://pastebin.com/d4MzJQbv

Comment: I didn't need to use any graphics debugger, I just forgot that texture coordinates have a different length from vertex positions. So, I created a self._len_ for the texture coords, and it worked.

Comment: Please don't put the solution in the question. Instead answer your own question.

Comment: Sure! I'm quite new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The solution

I noticed that texCoords have two elements per vertex and vertices have three. So I created a `self._len_` variable in the `TerrainRenderer` class to count the texCoord length separately. Here is my code for `TerrainRenderer`:

```
class TerrainRenderer:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.to_add = []
        self._len  = 0
        self._len_ = 0 # CHANGED

        self.parent = window

        self.vertices = []
        self.texCoords = []

        self.create_vbo(window)

        self.texture_manager = TextureAtlas()

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        if not USING_RENDERDOC:
            glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
            glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)

    def shared_context(self, window):
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, glfw.FALSE)
        window2 = glfw.create_window(500,500, "Window 2", None, window)
        glfw.make_context_current(window2)
        self.event.set()

        while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
            if len(self.to_add) > 0:
                i = self.to_add.pop(0)

                vertices = np.array(i[0], dtype=np.float32)
                texture_coords = np.array(i[1], dtype=np.float32)

                bytes_vertices = vertices.nbytes
                bytes_texCoords = texture_coords.nbytes

                verts = (GLfloat * len(vertices))(*vertices)
                texCoords = (GLfloat * len(texture_coords))(*texture_coords)

                log_vertex_addition((vertices, texture_coords), (bytes_vertices, bytes_texCoords), self._len*4, len(self.to_add))

                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
                glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self._len, bytes_vertices, verts)
                if not USING_RENDERDOC:
                    glVertexPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
                glFlush()
                
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_1)
                glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self._len_, bytes_texCoords, texCoords) # CHANGED
                if not USING_RENDERDOC:
                    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
                glFlush()

                self.vertices += i[0]
                self.texCoords += i[1]
                
                self._len += bytes_vertices
                self._len_ += bytes_texCoords # CHANGED

            glfw.poll_events()
            glfw.swap_buffers(window2)
        glfw.terminate()

    def create_vbo(self, window):
        self.vbo, self.vbo_1 = glGenBuffers (2)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 64000000, None, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_1)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 64000000, None, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        glfw.make_context_current(None)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.shared_context, args=[window], daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        self.event.wait()
        glfw.make_context_current(window)

    def add(self, vertices, texCoords):
        self.to_add.append((tuple(vertices), tuple(texCoords)))

    def render(self):
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)

        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        if not USING_RENDERDOC:
            glVertexPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_1)
        if not USING_RENDERDOC:
            glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)

        glDrawArrays (GL_QUADS, 0, self._len)

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glDisable(GL_BLEND)
```